# Do you have any tools to put here.com places on here.com map?

Tags: web, mobile, maps, here-api

Do your javascript SDK have a map view with places on it?
We didn’t find any suitable example how to show places by default (caffe, restaurants, museums, schools, etc) on the here.com maps. Are there any specific tools for this or we need to draw it on our side?
The same question for Android/iOS SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these POIs details in our geocoding and search section. with respect to JS, you can find the service for our latest version at following place : https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.14.0/api_reference/H.service.SearchService.html

For 3.0 version, check the example : https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/mrs_options , there is a parameter called pois which can be passed and it will show all POIs on the map

For android : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/4.2.0.0/dev_guide/topics/search.html
Service reference can be checked from 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/4.2.0.0/api_reference/index.html